# Can Mathematica solve $x^{b^2} + ax^b -1 = 0$ for $x$ with $a>0$, $b>1$?

Tags: equation-solving, algorithm

I have a problem that I can't seem to solve neither analytically nor with Mathematica. Namely, I have the expression $$x^{b^2} + ax^b - 1= 0,$$ which I want to solve for $x$ with $a>0$, $b>1$.

But I can't find a method in Mathematica that would provide an answer to this without specifying $a$ and $b$ (for example, Solve, Root, FindRoot and Reduce don't work). I am quite new to the software, however, so I was wondering whether I am just missing something or can this equation truly not be solved in general using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Abel-Ruffini theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem), there is no general solution in radicals to polynomial equations of degree five or higher, except for those with solvable Galois group. You did not specify whether the parameter b is integer. But even if it is, it is not possible to construct a general analytical solution of this equation with Mathematica.

Comment: Thank you, and I figured this would be the case. I guess I was just being naively hopeful Mathematica would nevertheless spit something out :) And no, $b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $b>1$, so not necessarily an integer. I assume there is no theorem that is more general than the Abel-Ruffini one you mention and that would apply here, is there? That is, for each particular $b$, the given equation is a beast that needs to be tackled individually and you cannot _a priori_ say whether you'll be successful in finding a root or not without knowing the value of $b$, right?

Comment: Let's take x>0 to deal with real-valued functions. The LHS of your equation is a monotonically increasing function of x (within the specified range of parameters), which at x=0 is equal to -1. Thus, it turns to zero at a single point x_1>0, but, generally speaking, x_1 can not be expressed via b and a using radicals. You can rely on a numerical solution, however, or construct an approximate analytic solution, e.g. via series expansion.

Comment: Yeah, I've already shown that there exists a unique real root, but was curious as to whether I could find an explicit expression for it in general. Too bad this isn't possible, but I probably don't need anything but existence anyway. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would leave `a` unassigned, set `b` to whatever you like, and solve for `x`.  Then you can pick the solution you like from the list:

```
With[{b = 2}, Solve[x^b^2 + a x^b == 0, x]]
```

With b=2, there are four solutions:

```
{{x -> 0}, {x -> 0}, {x -> -I Sqrt[a]}, {x -> I Sqrt[a]}}
```

Comment: I know, that would be trivial to solve, but I'm really interested in the general solution.

Comment: In that case, don't assign anything to b:  `Solve[x^b^2 + a x^b == 0, x]`

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I messed up on my question, sorry about that. I've edited the original post and the title. What you're saying works, but it doesn't work with the edited equation.

Comment: With the extra -1 in the equation, I would recommend my previous method (using `With`).  If Reduce can't solve the general case, you may be out of luck.

Comment: By With you mean choosing $b$ again, right? Yeah, as I said, I'm not really interested in such a simplification, and Reduce can't solve the general case. I get the "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce." message :/

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by x^(-b), take the log, and the Exp you will get:

```
x=Exp[Log[-a]/(b^2-b)]
```

Comment: You can try this also:

Comment: Solve[FullSimplify[(x^b^2 + a x^b ) x^(-b)] == 0, x]

Comment: Thanks, although as mentioned above, I messed up on my question. There should be an additional -1 in the equation, and I've now edited the original post. So I guess what you suggested would work, but not on the amended problem.